# Using Powershell to edit XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file that I need to amend the connection string within. Below is an example of the file.

```
<policy>
  <application-policy name="Part1">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/test=</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
  <application-policy name="Part2">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/test=</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
  <application-policy name="Part3">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/test=</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
  <application-policy name="Part4">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/test</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
</policy>
```

How can I change the string "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/test" that comes within `module-option` in the four places.

The string is always the same and will be replaced four times from the same variable.

Below is what I have tried but it is only changing the actually name "dbUrl" and only the first time.

```
$xmlFile = "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\login-Config.xml"
[xml]$doc = Get-Content $xmlFile
$node = $doc.SelectSingleNode("/policy/application-policy/authentication/login-module/module-option[@name='dbUrl']")
$node.name = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1521/test1"
$doc.Save($xmlFile)
```

Below is what I would like the output to look like.

```
<policy>
  <application-policy name="Part1">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1521/test1/test=</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
  <application-policy name="Part2">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1521/test1/test=</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
  <application-policy name="Part3">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1521/test1/test=</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
  <application-policy name="Part4">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1521/test1/test</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
</policy>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes) instead of `SelectSingleNode()` if you want all of them, and make sure you write to the `InnerText` property rather than `Name`:

```bsh
foreach($urlNode in $doc.SelectNodes("/policy/application-policy/authentication/login-module/module-option[@name='dbUrl']")){
  $urlNode.InnerText = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1521/test1"
}
```

Comment: Well that surely is a lot more direct than my answer +1

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen, thanks this did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could first iterate every `<application-policy>` node, then iterate every `<module-option>` node and only set `InnerText` to the new connectionstring with `name="dbUrl"`.

**Demo:**

```
# Create XML object from file
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path "test.xml"

# Iterate each policy node
foreach ($policy in $xml.policy.ChildNodes)
{
    # Iterate each module option node
    foreach ($moduleOption in $policy.authentication.'login-module'.'module-option')
    {
        # Only the dbUrl module option
        if ($moduleOption.name -eq "dbUrl")
        {
            $moduleOption.InnerText = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1521/test1/test"
        }
    }
}

# Save to output XML file
$xml.Save("output.xml")
```

**output.xml**

```
<policy>
  <application-policy name="Part1">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1521/test1/test</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
  <application-policy name="Part2">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1521/test1/test</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
  <application-policy name="Part3">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1521/test1/test</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
  <application-policy name="Part4">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="jboss.loginmodule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="dbUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1521/test1/test</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
</policy>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is actually very useful for me in other places so its nice to see how you drill down to the specific level.

Answer (score 0):

**Load your XML file like this** 
$doc = (gc $configPath) -as [xml]

**After storing xml in var.. now you can read and replace data**

```
   $doc.SelectSingleNode('//connectionStrings/add[@name="'+ $connectionName +'"]/@connectionString').'#text' = $connectionString

   $doc.Save($configPath)
```